# extracting specific integer value from mysql table using php in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I need to extract a specific value from a table knowing the id of the row in moodle
[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luIMc.png)

I tried previously to get the variable from another php class but no matter what it gives null so I get the idea if there is a method to get this value directly from the database table
the table name 'mdl_course_modules'
the id is the same as course module id
and need to extract this value from the column 'availability'

Edit

I tried to use the following

```
$viewslim = $DB->get_field_select('course_modules', 'availability' , "`availability` LIKE '%maxviews%' AND `id` = '$cm->id'",['id' => $cm->id], IGNORE_MISSING);
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $viewslim , $matches);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($matches); echo '</pre>';
```

it worked fine but if there is another integer in the line due to another active availability plugin, so how to get only the value after viewlimit only not any other possible integer in the line

```
{"op":"&","c":[{"type":"maxviews","viewslimit":"1"}],"showc":[true]}
```

that is what I get from var_dump

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be more than one availability condition, including more than one maxviews

Maybe use the existing availability code instead of a database query - it looks like you already know the `$cm->id` so will go from there

```
$modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($courseid);

// Get the module as a cm_info class.
$mod = $modinfo->get_cm($cm->id);

// Get the availability conditions.
$ci = new \core_availability\info_module($mod);
$tree = $ci->get_availability_tree();

// Children is a protected property, so use Reflection (available from PHP 8)
$reflectiontree = new \ReflectionClass($tree);
$reflectionchildren = $reflectiontree->getProperty('children');
$reflectionchildren->setAccessible(true);

$children = $reflectionchildren->getValue($tree);

$viewslimit = 0;

foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child instanceof \availability_maxviews\condition) {
        // This is a max views condition.

        // Viewslimit is protected so again use reflection.
        $reflectionmaxviews = new \ReflectionClass($child);
        $reflectionviewslimit = $reflectionmaxviews->getProperty('viewslimit');
        $reflectionviewslimit->setAccessible(true);

        $newviewslimit = (int)$reflectionviewslimit->getValue($child);

        // It's unlikely but its possible to add more than one max views condition.
        // So use the largest value.
        if ($newviewslimit > $viewslimit) {
            $viewslimit = $newviewslimit;
        }

    }
}

// Done, this is the views limit for this module.
echo $viewslimit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it, I hope it works fine till the end

```
$getviewslimit = $DB->get_field_select('course_modules', 'availability' , "`availability` LIKE '%maxviews%' AND `id` = '$cm->id'",['id' => $cm->id], IGNORE_MISSING);
if ($getviewslimit != null){
preg_match_all('/\"type\":\"maxviews\",\"viewslimit\":\"(\d+)/', $getviewslimit , $matches);
$viewslimit = $matches[1][0];

$a = new \stdclass();
$a->viewscount = $viewscount;
$a->viewslimit = ($viewslimit + $reset);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($a->viewslimit); echo '</pre>';
}
```

and it results exactly what I need

```
int(3)
int(7)
int(50)
```

Comment: You would probably be better off calling json_decode() on the availability value, then looping through the data to find what you wanted.